# Apple Core Data saving duplicates of entities when initializing entities

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am currently building an iOS app that utilizes Core Data to cache Firebase queries, so that my app won't be hitting the Firebase server multiple times for the same query.

My main issue right now is with fetching what will be labeled as `IdeaEntity`, where the initial fetch will result in the published array of `IdeaEntity` storing duplicates of the `IdeaEntity` elements. I will post images below, along with the code snippet for how I'm fetching IdeaEntity arrays from Core Data. However, when re-opening the app (when you close it down via app preview), the duplicates seem to disappear.

[iOS Simulator 16.2; Showing proof of duplicate IdeaEntity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BokwJ.png)

```swift
// Fetch either from Firebase or Core Data
func fetchIdeas() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<IdeaEntity>(entityName: "IdeaEntity")
        
        do {
            self.savedIdeas = try appContainer.viewContext.fetch(request)
            
            if self.savedIdeas.isEmpty {
                self.initialFetchIdeas()
            }
        } catch {
            print("ERROR - \(error)")
        }
    }

// Initial Function to fetch IdeaEntity
private func initialFetchIdeas() {
        do {
            let uid = self.firebaseService.fetchUserID()
            guard !uid.isEmpty else { throw AltyrErrors.cannotFetchUid }
            
            self.firebaseService.fetchUser(withUid: uid) { [weak self] user in
                guard let self = self else { return }
                self.firebaseService.fetchIdeas(user: user) { ideas in
                    guard !(ideas.isEmpty) else { return }

                    ideas.forEach { idea in
                        let newIdea = IdeaEntity(context: self.appContainer.viewContext)
                        
                        // ... Insert code for inserting parameters for `newIdea`
                        
                        if let feedback = idea.feedback {
                            let newFeedback = FeedbackEntity(context: self.appContainer.viewContext)
                            
                            // ... Insert code for inserting parameters for `newIdea` Feedback object
                            
                            newIdea.feedback = newFeedback
                        }
                    }
                    self.save()
                }
            }
        } catch {
            // TODO: Error handling...
            print("ERROR - \(error)")
        }
    }
```

Couple of assumptions:

1. `FirebaseService` functions are assumed to be 100% functional, as in they output the needed items in a proper manner.
2. The above functions are in a class named `CoreDataService`, which is a class that inherits from `ObservableObject`
3. `savedProjects` is a Published array of `IdeaEntity`

If there is a better manner of fetching with another library, a different method for fetching `IdeaEntity`, need any other code snippets / signatures, or anything else, please do let me know.

I had tried switching around `fetchIdea` with `initialFetchIdeas` within the private init (since `CoreDataService` is a singleton) to see if `fetchIdea` was missing anything that `initialFetchIdeas` had, though the result is the same (e.g., duplicate entities).

**Edit: TL;DR of the solution, just use `NSCache` if you have really complex objects. It's not worth the effort to utilize Core Data.**

Comment: How static is the data in Firestore?  You aren't doing anything about checking to see if documents already exist in core data. How do plan to update core data if new items are added to Firestore?  Using any form of persistent store as a cache probably isn't the best approach. I would use `NSCache` for in-memory caching.

Comment: What debugging have you done to see where the duplicates are coming from?

Comment: @Paulw11 The `CoreDataService` class has a function to use setData for Firebase, and to save the IdeaEntity into CoreData itself. However, I will update this post with my result for looking into `NSCache`; however if you're able to provide resource(s) for integrating `NSCache` into Firebase functions, please do share it.

I also had probed the savedIdea array using the LLDB debugger, and it seems like the duplicates aren't from any other functions besides `initializeFetchIdeas`, however I will look further and see if there are any other areas that the data could be getting duplicates from.

Comment: There can't be many places where you assign to `savedProjects`. You can set breakpoints and check the contents of the array. `NSCache` is essentially a dictionary; you can add objects keyed by their id and attempt to retrieve by id. To be honest you are probably over engineering things. I would start just by fetching your data from Firestore and not worry about anything else. If you have specific performance problems then you can look at addressing those

Comment: @Paulw11 Should also mention that the data in Firebase does have constantly updating sections (e.g., `Idea` objects are constantly being saved into Firebase from multiple users, users are able to make `Project` objects that allow them to store multiple `Idea` objects, etc). So there is a need for utilizing constantly updating objects.

Comment: @Paulw11 Ah alright, all good. I was factoring in with trying to lower the amount of times the user fetches from Firebase as possible. I'll certainly look into using `NSCache`, and revamp the project to utilize it instead, both to keep things simple while still having the better user experience.

Comment: If your database is constant changing then you probably don't want to mess around with caching or local storage. Just use Firestore directly.  It lets you get updates as soon as a document is added or changed and is implemented pretty efficiently using protobufs and persistent connections under the hood.